# Fix several values : mdx query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have this `mdx` query :

```
SELECT 
  NonEmpty
  (
    {
      [Dim Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country]
    }
  ) ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty
  (
    {
        [Due Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year]
      * 
        [Due Date].[French Month Name].MEMBERS
    }
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [AW Cube]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Sales Amount];
```

This gives me the result: for each month of year my sales amount

What I want to do is to get result only for 2 years ..

For one year I did this

```
SELECT 
  NonEmpty
  (
    {
      [Dim Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country]
    }
  ) ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty
  (
    {
        [Due Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008]
      * 
        [Due Date].[French Month Name].MEMBERS
    }
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [AW Cube]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Sales Amount];
```

But for two years i didn't found anything !!

Answer (score 2):

How about :

```
NONEMPTY(
   { [Due Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008], [Due Date].[Calendar Year].&[2009] }
   * { [Due Date].[French Month Name].MEMBERS }

) ON ROWS
```

This is actually a shortcut of the [crossjoin](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Crossjoin.html) function.